# Visual Studio stopped publishing js files compiled from ts after 1.8 update

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

I have a VS 2015 TS project.  It has been publishing fine, meaning that the typescript files are included in the project, but not the *.js files, but the js files have been getting published as expected.

However, after updating to the 1.8 beta, the *.js files are no longer being published.

Makes no sense, and I am not even sure the update is the issue, but I have no other explanation.  No other changes were made to the project.  I updated yesterday, and actually did several successful publishes before the *.js stopped getting published.

Other js files get published, but not the ones that are compiled from ts.

If I include the compiled js in the project (and thus source control) then it does publish correctly.

I just want to make sure I didn't screw something up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I include the compiled js in the project (and thus source control) then it does publish correctly.

You are not the only one.

> I just want to make sure I didn't screw something up here.

You didn't. That the new defacto way now.