# Compiling TS fails because it can't delete js files which are in source control

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260598/visual-studio-stopped-publishing-js-files-compiled-from-ts-after-1-8-update).

I have added all the generated files to the Vs project, and it publishes successfully.  However, when I build the project, I get 38 errors telling me that VS is "unable to delete *.js because access to the path is denied."  In other words, source control has put a read-only lock on all of those files and is not able to unlock them automatically.

I don't see any way around this other than manually checking out every compiled javascript file so the compiler can do it's work.

Comment: VS2015? Does compilation goes through by Grunt? Why don't you just remove js files from source control?

Comment: Because as of TS 1.8, VS does not publish the generated js files unless they are included in the project (before I updated, I did not include them).  See the question linked above. I am not using Grunt, just VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try going to their route and checking if the files are read only. I usually have to change this when I get latest version from my code in VS2013. You can just uncheck the "Read only" option from the whole containing folder.

BTW, don't delete all those files from source control, just exclude them.

Comment: Actually, you have a good point. In any case, I downgraded back to TS 1.7 and all is well.